# .NET reflection on system assemblies fails on System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

I have a language compiler that I've just updated to target .NET 4.0 and the metadata generator for framework assemblies now fails on System.Data.dll, while all others work fine (mscorlib, System, etc.)

The metadata generator simply loads assemblies, reflects over all the types and memberinfo and generates a stub class for the language.

I'm using Assembly.Load() and/or `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()`

> *Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
>   an incorrect format.*

It is built for "AnyCPU". I'm running Windows 7/x64 with .NET 4.5 update installed.

Comment: I had this problem a couple of months ago and this link helped me:
http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.co.il/2010/12/could-not-load-file-or-assembly.html

Did you bump into this?

Comment: According to Google "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format", e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2009/06/21/tip-of-the-day-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-net-p-invoke-issue.aspx it seems to be a problem with 32bit vs 64bit. Don't know about 64bits but in my cases it was always necessary to mark the EXE calling the ..Load as x86 so that it would load only 32bit libraries. It should be possible to load both 32bit and 64bit at the same time using Mono.Cecil

Comment: Yep, this resolved it. I can live with x86 for colastub, since it is called as a child process and returns metadata as text. My actual need is to access the type metadata from .NET assemblies so I can expose them as Cola classes. I may consider Mono.Cecil. Is it written in .NET itself, or native C/C++? Unfortunately, I started the Cola compiler 10+ years ago as a hobby, when I was using C++ as my primary language, before Mono existed, and now I regret not writing it in C#. I would love to be able to directly access the CLR assemblies without using a stub program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `corflags` tool to analyze the assemblies, you should see that `ILONLY: 0` for System.Data.dll while the others (mscorlib, System) `ILONLY: 1`. More information regarding ILONLY can be found at [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slessard/archive/2010/04/09/types-of-managed-code-assemblies.aspx).

**Thus, the assemblies were built differently and you should not expect reflection to work for all.** System.Data.dll seems to be a mixed-mode assembly, which is always bitness dependent.

If you cannot run your app as 32 bit so as to load the 32 bit assemblies, you might consider Mono.Cecil as @xmojmr said, as [it supports reading mixed-mode assemblies](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: Thanks, switching app to x86 fixed the problem. It is fine for this to run as x86 because it is a stub generator that the compiler runs as a child process to read the type metadata. Thanks!